# It is possible to get G-WAN working on Google Cloud Compute or Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, listener, google-compute-engine, g-wan, hypervisor

I am currently working on a test deployment of a static CMS using G-WAN. Once a copy the files to the server using SSH and trying to start G-WAN I receive the following message:

- no listener in /home/[ELASTIC_COMPUTING_USER]/[GWAN_BINARY_DIRECTORY]

[1] This is the dump from gwan.log when using the command './gwan'

```
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] G-WAN 4.3.14 64-bit (Mar 14 2013 07:33:12)
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Local Time: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 00:47:04 GMT-4
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] RAM: (732.98 MiB free + 0 shared + 0 buffers) / 992.87 MiB total
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Physical Pages: 732.98 MiB / 992.87 MiB
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] DISK: 4.79 GiB free / 5.10 GiB total
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  /dev/xvda1     xfs       6.0G  1.3G  4.8G  21% /
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  devtmpfs       devtmpfs  487M     0  487M   0% /dev
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs     497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs     497M   13M  484M   3% /run
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs     497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Page-size:4,096 Child-max:7,788 Stream-max:16
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] CPU: 1x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]  0 id: 0     0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Cores: possible:0-14 present:0 online:0 
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] L1d cache:   32K line:64     0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] L1i cache:   32K line:64     0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] L2  cache:  256K line:64     0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] L3  cache:25600K line:64     0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] NUMA node #1 0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] CPU(s):1, Core(s)/CPU:1, Thread(s)/Core:1
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Bogomips: 5,000.07
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Hypervisor: XenVMMXenVMM
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]   using   1 workers 0[1]0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT]   among   1 threads 0[1]0
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] 64-bit little-endian (least significant byte first)
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] \S (3.10.0-123.) 64-bit
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] user: root (uid:0), group: root (uid:0)
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] system  fd_max: 1,024
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] program fd_max: 1,024
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] updated fd_max: 500,000
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] Available network interfaces (2):
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] XXX.X.X.X
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] XXX.XX.XX.XXX
[Wed Oct 01 04:47:04 2014 GMT] * no listener in    /home/[ELASTIC_COMPUTING_USER]/[GWAN_BINARY_DIRECTORY]
```

I check and i get the same output even using this command './gwan -d:[ELASTIC_GROUP]:[ELASTIC_USER]'. Trying to run G-WAN in daemon mode, there's no success.

Additionally, and after trying to start G-WAN as daemon, I get this lines:

```
[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 04:47:04 GMT] * child normal exit(1)
[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 04:47:04 GMT] * child abort(8)
[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 04:47:04 GMT] * child abort(8)
[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 04:47:04 GMT] * child died 3 times within 3 seconds
```

The directory structure I have is:

```
/home/[ELASTIC_COMPUTING_USER]/[GWAN_BINARY_DIRECTORY]/XXX.XX.XX.XXX_80/#XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Where XXX.XX.XX.XXX is the local IP from the 'ifconfig' command output. Do I need to use the external/public IP or is this ok?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no listener in ...
>
> user: root

You are using 'root' to run G-WAN.

So you chould apply access rights to your `/home/.../gwan` directory 
to make it possible for G-WAN to access its files.

Or, and this is certainly preferable, you should install G-WAN under a directory controlled by 'root' like `/opt/gwan`.

> G-WAN 4.3.14 64-bit (Mar 14 2013 07:33:12)
>
> child abort(8)

This hypervisor compatibility issue has been fixed in more recent versions of G-WAN, starting with v4.10+ if I remember well.

Your version is more than one year old. Registered users have access to v4.12.19, the latest stable version publicly released.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gil, your guidance made work in the right direction now the problem is solved. What do I need to advance and/or cooperate with the development of this fantastic server?

Comment: It all depends on your means and goals, but to help you can develop G-WAN-based applications and/or add-ons, or make us useful features suggestions, or write blog articles to explain your experience with G-WAN, etc.